# Create a delete button that lets users pick something to delete - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello I am in still a beginner in JavaScript and am trying to figure out how I would go about adding a delete button to my chrome extension that lets users pick something to delete.

I tried using the .pop but this just deletes the last thing listed which doesn't work because I want users to be able to pick which item to delete. Not sure how to go about doing this and my current lack of knowledge with JavaScript has made it harder to be able to search for the right answer. Below is my code any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
let myLeads = [];
const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el");
const inputBtn = document.getElementById("input-btn");
const ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el");
const deleteBtn = document.getElementById("delete-btn");
const leadsFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myLeads"));
const tabBtn = document.getElementById("tab-btn");
const deleteOneAtATime = document.getElementById(`deleteone-btn`);

if (leadsFromLocalStorage) {
  myLeads = leadsFromLocalStorage;
  render(myLeads);
}

tabBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    myLeads.push(tabs[0].url);
    localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads));
    render(myLeads);
  });
});

function render(leads) {
  let listItems = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < leads.length; i++) {
    listItems += `
            <li>
                <a target='_blank' href='${leads[i]}'>
                    ${leads[i]}
                </a>
            </li>
        `;
  }
  ulEl.innerHTML = listItems;
}

deleteBtn.addEventListener("dblclick", function () {
  localStorage.clear();
  myLeads = [];
  render(myLeads);
});

inputBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  myLeads.push(inputEl.value);
  inputEl.value = "";
  localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads));
  render(myLeads);
});

deleteOneAtATime.addEventListener("click", function () {
  myLeads.pop(inputEl.value);
  inputEl.value = "";
  localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads));
  render(myLeads);
});
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Create an input element with type="text" and id="input-el" -->
    <input type="text" id="input-el" />
    <!-- Create a SAVE INPUT button with id="input-btn" -->
    <button id="input-btn">SAVE INPUT</button>
    <button id="tab-btn">SAVE TAB</button>
    <button id="delete-btn">DELETE ALL</button>
    <button id="deleteone-btn">Delete one at a time</button>

    <ul id="ul-el"></ul>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When does this script run compared to your html? How exactly does the user choose the item they want to delete? Do they type it in the `input-el` and then click `deleteOneAtATime`? Can you include your html as well?

Comment: Here is the HTML my apologies.

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Create an input element with type="text" and id="input-el" -->
    <input type="text" id="input-el" />
    <!-- Create a SAVE INPUT button with id="input-btn" -->
    <button id="input-btn">SAVE INPUT</button>
    <button id="tab-btn">SAVE TAB</button>
    <button id="delete-btn">DELETE ALL</button>
    <button id="deleteone-btn">Delete one at a time</button>

    <ul id="ul-el"></ul>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: Added the HTML to the original post. 

The user saves either the tab or something they type through the save input which references the input button or the save tab button which references the tab button. Currently the only way to erase them is to the delete all doubleclick button. I want to add a way for a user to just delete one thing at a time which they can pick. I'm trying to focus on making a new button for this which after clicking then clicking the item they want to delete,  would delete it from the list. However I am open to any easier ways to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove an item, you can use `filter` - here is a small sample assuming strings

```js
const myLeads = ['val1','val2','val3']
document.write(JSON.stringify(myLeads));

const myNewLeads = myLeads.filter((x) => x!== 'val2')
document.write(JSON.stringify(myNewLeads));
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete the element assuming that `inputEl` has a valid value you can use `indexOf()` to get the element index and use `splice()` to update the array.

```
deleteOneAtATime.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if(myLeads.indexOf(inputEl.value)!=-1{
    myLeads.splice(myLeads.indexOf(inputEl.value),1);
    inputEl.value = "";
    localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads));
    render(myLeads);
  } 
});
```

The function splice is used as follows **`splice(startingIndex,deleteCount, item1, item2, ....)`**

> `startingIndex` is the index from where the element will be removed

> `deleteCount`(Optional) is the number indicating the number of elements to be removed from `startingIndex`

> `items`(Optional) are the replacing elements

So when the function `myLeads.splice(myLeads.indexOf(inputEl.value),1)` is called it starts from the index of `inputEl.value` and removes one element from the array which is the `inputEl.value`. For more info you can refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Could you explain what this line is saying I am a bit confused on what the splice function does in this circumstance along with how the ,1 plays a role:

myLeads.splice(myLeads.indexOf(inputEl.value),1)

Comment: Hey I have edited the answer please refer.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked but I figured out that if I just use shift and pop I can let users delete from the beginning and end which at the very least helps limit it down a bit.

Here's the new JS code referencing a new HTML button called shift-btn:

```
let myLeads = [];
const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el");
const inputBtn = document.getElementById("input-btn");
const ulEl = document.getElementById("ul-el");
const deleteBtn = document.getElementById("delete-btn");
const leadsFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myLeads"));
const tabBtn = document.getElementById("tab-btn");
const deleteOneAtATime = document.getElementById(`deleteone-btn`);
const shiftBtn = document.getElementById(`shift-btn`);

if (leadsFromLocalStorage) {
  myLeads = leadsFromLocalStorage;
  render(myLeads);
}

tabBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    myLeads.push(tabs[0].url);
    localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads));
    render(myLeads);
  });
});

function render(leads) {
  let listItems = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < leads.length; i++) {
    listItems += `
            <li>
                <a target='_blank' href='${leads[i]}'>
                    ${leads[i]}
                </a>
            </li>
        `;
  }
  ulEl.innerHTML = listItems;
}

deleteBtn.addEventListener("dblclick", function () {
  localStorage.clear();
  myLeads = [];
  render(myLeads);
});

inputBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  myLeads.push(inputEl.value);
  inputEl.value = "";
  localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads));
  render(myLeads);
});
//if user clicks this button then it will delete what they click on after thats located within the input el field
deleteOneAtATime.addEventListener("click", function () {
  myLeads.pop(inputEl.value);
  inputEl.value = "";
  localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads));
  render(myLeads);
});
//if you want to delete a specific element of the array, you need to search its id
//instead of justing pushing the value, push an object, containing a value and an unique id
//that way, you can search the id of the item and delete it

shiftBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  myLeads.shift(inputEl.value);
  inputEl.value = "";
  localStorage.setItem("myLeads", JSON.stringify(myLeads));
  render(myLeads);
});
```